# Segfault reading lazy bytestring past 2^18 bytes

Tags: haskell, ghc, lazy-evaluation, mmap, bytestring

Consider the following code: http://hpaste.org/90394

I am memory mapping a large 460mb file to a lazy ByteString. The length of the ByteString reports `471053056`.

When `nxNodeFromID file 110000` is changed to a lower node ID, ie: `10000`, it works perfectly. However; as soon as I try and serialize anything past exactly 2^18 bytes (`262144`) of the ByteString I get `Segmentation fault/access violation in generated code` and termination.

I'm running Windows and using GHC 7.4.2.

Please advise whether this is my fault, or some issue with the laziness, or, some  issue with Haskell.

Comment: Your `getNXNode` doesn't match the `NXNode` data definition. If that's intentional, it would be worth a comment. But I don't see how that would cause a segfault here.

Comment: @DanielFischer `NXNode 0 <$> ...` :)

Comment: Yes, but you `skip` 20 bytes, and read only 12 per node.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. `getNXMetadata` contributes to 2 (type) + 8 (data) optional bytes (which are null if they aren't used) totaling 20 for the size of the node (when added to the 4 + 4 + 2 read in `getNXNode`).

Comment: Makes sense. I suppose once `getNXMetadata` is complete, it becomes more or less obvious.

Comment: Does the problem persist if you use `mmapFileByteString` instead of `mmapFileByteStringLazy`? (You'd need to wrap the returned strict `ByteString` of that in a `fromChunks [buf]` or so to get a lazy `ByteString` for the rest of your code to work with.)

Comment: Yes, that works (however, I think I lose laziness now?). Is this segfault a wierd glitch in GHC?

Comment: Sure, you lose laziness. But the idea was to get a hint what the problem could be. I suspect it may be "-- FIXME: might be we need NOINLINE pragma here, investigate later" (concerning `mapChunk handle (offset,size) = unsafePerformIO $`), but it could be something else. Can't really investigate, though. (Well, if I _had to_, I could boot into Windows; but I'd still need a file to work on, and a great incentive to expose myself to the inconvenience.)

Comment: Sorry, that's not my area of expertise. Besides, I don't think a Windows core-dump would work with gdb on Linux. You could try to contact the maintainer of `mmap`, he should have a better idea what the problem might be.

Comment: BTW you should make the fields of your type strict. Better semantics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that I have updated mmap to correctly include NOINLINE pragma at strategic point in the code. mmap-0.5.9 available for grabs. Let me know if the issue persists.
Edit: yes, I'm the author of mmap.

Comment: While it appears you're the mmap author, this is not totally clear from your answer. I would consider adding more information.

Comment: HI, I have the same error with latest version of your library. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53715138/address-boundary-error-in-haskell-application