# (Address boundary error) in Haskell application

Tags: haskell, memory-mapped-files

I'm trying to develop haskell replacement for `less` pager.

Full code is here
https://github.com/purpleP/pager.git

```
buildInitialState :: IO TuiState
buildInitialState = do
    (file : args) <- getArgs
    bs <- mmapFileByteStringLazy file Nothing
    pure (TuiState (V.fromList (BC.lines bs)) 0)
```

That's how I read file. It works fine with files of 20Mb but doesn't work for 100Mb file. Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug in mmap library?

`terminated by signal SIGSEGV (Address boundary error)` Is the exact error I get.

Comment: What is the error message you are getting?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Address boundary error. I thought It's clear from description, sorry.

Comment: This sounds very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/17292048/625403. I see you're using the latest version of mmap but perhaps the intended fix did not actually fix things?